# jQuery Select Visible Elements After Append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select visible children after appending them into a temp `div`.

But I got **undefined**. I've prepared a pen here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/XWWxagO)

```js
function createTemp() {
  var innerObj = $('.main');
  var el = $('<div class="doc-temp" style="display: none;"><div class="temp2">' + innerObj.html() + '</div></div>');
  $('body').append(el);
  var visible = el.children(':visible');
  return visible;
}

console.log(createTemp().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span>Well</span> Hello
  <span>Three</span> Hi Hello
  <span style="display: none;">Four</span>
  <span>Five</span> See you
</div>
```

Comment: Also note that when concatenating `innerObj` to a string you'll just get `[Object object]`, not the HTML. You need to append the DOM structures not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element is hidden it will NOT have ANY :visible descendants!

Also you need the HTML of main

If you want the children that WOULD be visible if the PARENT was, you can do this:

```js
function createTemp() {
  var innerObj = $('.main').html();
  var el = $('<div class="doc-temp"><div class="temp2"></div></div>');
  $("body").append(el);
  $(".temp2").append(innerObj);
  var children = $(".temp2")[0].childNodes;
  return [...children].map(el => { 
    if (el.getAttribute) {
      return el.getAttribute("style") === "display: none;" ? null : el.outerHTML
    }  
    return el === null ? null : el.textContent;
  })
}

$("#ta").val(createTemp().join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span>Well</span> Hello
  <span>Three</span> Hi Hello
  <span style="display: none;">Four</span>
  <span>Five</span> See you
</div>

<textarea rows="100" cols="100" id="ta"></textarea>
```

Comment: I've tried your method on pen. But still undefined when I try to select :visible

Comment: I will make some process on the HTML text which are visible

Comment: If your el is hidden it will NOT have ANY :visible descendants! Note I removed the display:none in the first example and changed to children in the second

Comment: But I'm not selecting the .doc-temp's children. Only .doc-temp and one of the spam have display:none; I want to select the elements except of the span which has display:none

Comment: I repeat: Children of a hidden elements are also hidden

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. And how can I select the elements which has no display:none; inside of an not visible element

Comment: And I removed display:none on the .doc-temp, even like that children(':visible') doesn't work at all

Comment: I updated again - I did not remove the display non span

Answer (score -1):

Modify your function to below:

```
function createTemp(){
   var innerObj = $('.main');
   var el = '<div class="doc-temp" style="display: none;"><div class="temp2">' + innerObj.html() + '</div></div>';
    $('body').append(el);
    var visible = $('.main').find(':visible');
    return visible;
}
```

After this change, you can iterate through the `visible` array. Use `$.each` for this iteration process.

Comment: That is pointless. Why append if he does not access the appended elements and he cannot access the :visible of the appended elements because they are all hidden

Comment: I've only corrected his code which was wrongly written. It's his requirement what elements he want to mark hidden and what's visible.

Comment: @mplungjan Make sure you understand an answer first before marking it downvote.

Comment: I understand the answer. It does not answer the question "Select Visible Elements After Append - I'm trying to select visible children after appending them into a temp div." - that is not what you are doing